# Brunch including select2 styles

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, phoenix-framework, brunch

I have this kind of brunch-config.js, with select2@4.0.3 as dependency:

```js
exports.config = {
  npm: {
    enabled: true,
    globals: {
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    }
  },
  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: {
        "js/app.js": [
          "node_modules/phoenix/priv/static/phoenix.js",
          "node_modules/phoenix_html/priv/static/phoenix_html.js",
          "node_modules/process/browser.js",
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.js",
          "js/app.js",
        ]
      }
    },
    stylesheets: {
      joinTo: {
        "css/app.css": [
          "node_modules/select2/dist/css/select.min.css",
          "css/phoenix.css",
          "css/app.scss"
        ]
      }
    },
    templates: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"
    }
  },

  conventions: {
    assets: /^(static)/
  },

  paths: {
    watched: ["static", "css", "js", "vendor"],
    public: "../priv/static"
  },

  plugins: {
    babel: {
      ignore: [/vendor/]
    }
  },

  modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      "js/app.js": ["js/app"]
    },
  }
};
```

As I understand, brunch takes stylesheets from my stylesheets.joinTo and concats them together in the output file, yet the select2 styles are missing from the output file app.css.